# Javascript function's property that contains its code

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to `Javascript`. I did a course sometime back and I am trying to remember a concept about that all the functions are objects that will contain a **property** that will *contain the code written inside that function* and another property that contains name of the function.

I tried that and I found name property like below. but not able to find the code property. Does that really exist or I may be wrong.

```js
console.log(
  (function f() {
    a = 1
  }.name)
)
```

so the property should return

> a=1

Not trying to do anything. I am brushing up my JS as I want to learn angular.

Comment: Here are a list of keys found on Functions object prototype.  Probably what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Comment: Are you trying something like `({a:1}).a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but not able to find the code property. Does that really exist or I may be wrong.

It exists *conceptually*, but it is an **internal** property, which cannot be accessed from user code. It's called `[[ECMAScriptCode]]`. See the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects) for more details.

In reality though, browsers could implement functions in any way they want, as long as they behave as described in the spec.

---

What you can do in user code is call the function's [`toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString). That will return a string representation of the function itself, though the exact representation is implementation dependent.

Comment: Thanks great link to the spec!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for something like the following:

```
function f(){
    console.log("a = 1");
};

console.log(f.toSource());
console.log(f.toString());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agraymd/ar5hgkv8/1/

.toSource is however not a standard feature. From the MDN:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

`function.toSring();` seems to be a better alternative, which is a standard feature. More on that here:

[.toString();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)

Comment: Yes tosource seems only for gecko engines

Answer (score 0):

Try `f.toString()` where `f` is the function you wish to obtain the source code of.